# By comparing boxplots, how to tell which sample is more likely to have outliers?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, median

For example, from three boxplots, like these

[image: Boxplots]

how could I tell which one is more likely to have outliers?

By outliers, I mean values below $Q1 - 1.5 * (Q3-Q1)$ or above $Q3 + 1.5 * (Q3-Q1)$

Comment: What do you define as an outlier?

Comment: values below $Q1 - 1.5 * (Q3-Q1)$ or above $Q3 + 1.5 * (Q3-Q1)$

Comment: Great. So in the boxplots, that corresponds to points on each of the "whiskers" that are more than 1.5 box-lengths away from the box - which means that you get more outliers the longer the whiskers are relative to the box size. And which box is that true for?